# mail() not returning any value PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

I'm a beginner in `php` and found a simple mail function. Following is the code:

```
private function sendEmail() {

  $to = $this - > email;
  $subject = $this - > subject;
  $message = $this - > name. " : ". $this - > message;
  $header = "From: ".$this - > email;

  $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

  echo $to, $subject, $message, $header, $mail, "End";

  if ($mail) {
    $this - > response_status = 1;
    $this - > response_html = 'Thank You!';
  } else {
    echo "Mail not found";
  }
}
```

When I call it from Javascript, it always lands in error block of `$.ajax` but no error message it thrown. When I check response of ajax call in network tab, I get proper values of all variables ($to, $subject, $name, $message, $header), but `$mail` is always blank.

Also I get *Mail not found* from else block.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm running it on localhost on XAMPP (on Ubuntu 15.10).

Following is the snapshot of response:

[image]

Comment: It's probably [`false` instead of blank](https://3v4l.org/XOofE). Debug it using [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see what it contains.

Comment: you haven't shown us how you're calling it from Ajax. That's a separate issue. in PHP, the value of $mail will be either true or false. The fact you're going into the block in your function that returns "mail not found" suggests it's returning false.

Comment: So is the actual issue here the fact that this code is being handled by your error block in your javascript?  Show your Javascript, then...  Also, this function doesn't `return` anything. Maybe that's your error, but we can't tell because we don't have enough code

Comment: @PeeHaa, you are right. Its returning false. Do I need a smtp server? I read on w3schools, `mail` does not require any installation.

Comment: You need at least some agent / transport capable of sending mails on your machine. `mail` just passes the mail to whatever is going to actually send it. Or use an external smtp server.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter the issue is its throwing error. As **PeeHaa** has already clarified, I'm getting false. So issue is either in my PHP code or some missing configuration.

Answer (score 2):

[How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Check that out. Should work for ya, it's more than likely that you don't have any application to actually send the mail - e.g. sendmail for *nix.

Comment: I did try to follow the steps but now getting another. I have installed *ssmtp* and now getting this error: *ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587*. But still thanks for the help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/677146/ssmtp-with-gmail-cannot-open-587587 - try this?